# Flashing Yellow Belisha Beacon Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener

Basically, I have to have my Belisha Beacon start off flashing and it has to flash alternatively between orange and light grey and when I click the Steady button, the light has to stay Orange. When I click the Flash button, it has to go back to flashing. I have sorted out the Steady button but when I run the program, it doesn't start off as flashing, my Beacon doesn't flash at all. Here is my code so far, thank you for any help.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class BelishaBeacon {

    public class Drawing extends JPanel {

        private int x = 125;
        private int y = 80;
        private boolean changeColors = false;


        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            //creating the shapes
            Rectangle box1 = new Rectangle(165, 180, 20, 45);
            Rectangle box2 = new Rectangle(165, 225, 20, 45);
            Rectangle box3 = new Rectangle(165, 270, 20, 45);
            Rectangle box4 = new Rectangle(165, 315, 20, 45);
            Rectangle box5 = new Rectangle(165, 360, 20, 45);
            Rectangle box6 = new Rectangle(165, 405, 20, 45);

            //drawing the shapes
            Ellipse2D.Double ball = new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 100, 100);
            g2.draw(ball);
            g2.draw(box1);
            g2.draw(box2);
            g2.draw(box3);
            g2.draw(box4);
            g2.draw(box5);
            g2.draw(box6);
            //coloring the shapes
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.fill(box1);
            g2.fill(box3);
            g2.fill(box5);
            g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            g2.fill(ball);

            if (changeColors) {
                g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
                g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 100, 100));
            }

            changeColors = false;
        }

        public void changeColors() {
            changeColors = true;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public BelishaBeacon() {
        //Creation of frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(350, 570);
        frame.setTitle("Belisha Beacon");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        final Drawing shapes = new Drawing();

        JButton jbtFlash = new JButton("Flash");
        final JButton jbtSteady = new JButton("Steady");
        jbtSteady.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        shapes.changeColors();
                    }
                });

        //Positioning
        JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
        controlPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 0, 0));
        controlPanel.add(jbtFlash);
        controlPanel.add(jbtSteady);

        frame.add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(shapes);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BelishaBeacon();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add a `javax.swing.Timer` to you code and in the `actionListener` of this timer you should call the `repaint()` method of your `Drawing` panel. Also in your Steady button you should stop the timer, and the flash button you should start the timer.

Comment: @STaefi could you show me how that looks like please? I am relatively new to Java that's why . Thank you :).

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this code in your `paintComponent` of you `Drawing` panel as follow:

```
changeColors = !changeColors;

if (changeColors) {
    g2.setColor(Color.darkGray);
    g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 100, 100));
}
```

Also in you constructor of `BelishaBeacon` class you should initialize the `javax.swing.Timer` and your `Flash` and `Steady` buttons like this:

```
private Timer timer; // Don't forget to add this to your BelishaBeacon class and not in your Drawing panel

public BelishaBeacon() {
    //Creation of frame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(350, 570);
    frame.setTitle("Belisha Beacon");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    final Drawing shapes = new Drawing();

    timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            shapes.repaint();
        }
    });

    JButton jbtFlash = new JButton("Flash");
    jbtFlash.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            timer.start(); 
        }
    });
    final JButton jbtSteady = new JButton("Steady");
    jbtSteady.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                timer.stop();
            }
        });

    //Positioning
    //... your other codes here

    // in last line here, start the timer:
    timer.start(); 
}
```

Good Luck.

Comment: thank you so much, the flashing worked, one small thing, I wanted the beacon to be already flashing when I run the program as in I want it to be flashing at the start without me clicking the flash button and when I click on steady , it stay on the colour it stopped flashing on so it is not always steady on orange.

Comment: you should start the timer in the last line in constructor of `BelishaBeacon` class. See the edit again. Also please don't forget to select the green check besides the answer.

Comment: As a general nitpick, because `paintComponent` can be called at any time for any number of reasons, many without your interaction or knowledge, you should never be changing the state of the component from within the `paintComponent` method (try resizing the component when the `Timer` isn't running!)

Comment: You are right @MadProgrammer, but I didn't want to provide the whole solution to his homework. As you mentioned resizing or any other interaction can cause the `paintComponent` to be called. It is obvious to change the state in the the timer's `actionListener` using some setter and getter